# "undefined reference to symbol" error when using `ld` to link

Tags: c, glibc, undefined-reference

I am new to writing programs on Linux.  I have a single module program that uses `shm_open`, `ftruncate`, `mmap`, `fork`, and `wait`.  I compiled this program with `gcc -c` and then linked it with `ld -lrt` (librt is needed for `shm_open`) and I got a strange linker error:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'waitpid@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

The manpage for `wait` says

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
   waitid():
       Since glibc 2.26: _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
       Glibc 2.25 and earlier:
           _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

but putting `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` in the code doesn't help, and if I do

```
gcc -c -D _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

the compiler says an implicit declaration of `ftruncate`.

I am running Ubuntu under VMWare.  GCC is version `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you try compiling with `gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -c`?  There's is a [waitpid](https://github.com/walac/glibc/blob/glibc-2.2.5/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c) in glibc 2.2.5

Comment: thank you, but... no

it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I compiled this program with `gcc -c` and then linked it with `ld -lrt`

Until you are much more experienced, you should not attempt to invoke `ld` directly.  Instead, link your programs, as well as compiling them, using the `gcc` (or `cc`) command.  For your use case, a command line like this:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.o -lrt
```

should work.  (Note the placement of the `-lrt`; in most cases, `-l` options need to go *after* object files on the command line, for tedious historical reasons.)

Under the hood, when you link a program using the `gcc` command, it runs `ld` for you, but it includes a *whole bunch* of additional arguments.   These are all needed to construct normal programs, and they're complicated enough that normal programmers shouldn't have to worry about them.  One of the extra arguments is `-lc`, telling `ld` to include the core of the C runtime library, which provides the definition of `waitpid@@GLIBC_2.2.5` that was missing from your link.  (Don't just try sticking `-lc` on the `ld` command line yourself.  Actually, do try it.  You'll discover that you only get an even more mysterious error message, probably something like `warning: cannot find entry symbol _start` or `undefined reference to __bswapsi2` or who even knows.)

You can see what all those extra arguments are, if you're curious, by adding a `-v` to the above `gcc` invocation, but it's a big mess and only compiler developers need to worry about most of it.

Why is it the `gcc` command and not the `ld` command that knows all these extra arguments you need to link a normal program correctly?  It's mostly historical, but the idea is that `ld` is minimal, so if you're doing something unusual (e.g. linking an operating system kernel) you don't need to turn anything normal *off*, you just need to start from zero and build up.  But, for normal programs, people can use `(g)cc` and not have to worry about the extra arguments.

Incidentally, the stuff you found in the manual about `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is not about how to make `wait` available at link time; it's about how to make the *declaration* of `wait` available at *compile* time.  Also, the value you define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to matters.  Defining it as `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` rather than `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` is why you got a complaint about an implicit declaration of `ftruncate`.

Comment: thank you very very much !!

it worked!!

just for clarify

in fact, at first, I compiled gcc -o p p.c (for example)

but it said undefined references to shm_open() and shm_unlink()

then I payed attention to **Link with _-lrt_**  in manual of shm_open()

I've tried with gcc -Wl,-lrt and gcc -Wl,<-lrt> and so on (according to gcc manual to pass options to linker, but they didn' t work

Finally I did gcc -c only and then ld -lrt with the described problem

now I made gcc -o p p.c -lrt and it worked !!


thanks a lot again

now I tried

Comment: @SergioStarkloff `-Wl,-lrt` probably would have worked if you'd put it at the end of the command line instead of right after `gcc`. For future reference, `-Wl,` is only necessary for unusual linker options that the `gcc` program doesn't recognize. `-Wl,-lrt` is functionally the same as `-lrt` because `gcc` does recognize `-l` options.

Comment: @SergioStarkloff See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/388520 for an explanation of why the `-l` options have to go at the end of the command line.

Comment: Thank you friend.

You are a teacher for sure (but if you're not... you should be :-)